# Length of a UTF-8 byte sequence

Tags: code-golf, integer

Determine the length of a UTF-8 byte sequence given its first byte. The following table shows which ranges map to each possible length:

```
  Range    Length
---------  ------
0x00-0x7F    1
0xC2-0xDF    2
0xE0-0xEF    3
0xF0-0xF4    4
```

<sub>Notes on gaps in the table: 0x80-0xBF are continuation bytes, 0xC0-0xC1 would start an overlong, invalid sequence, 0xF5-0xFF would result in a codepoint beyond the Unicode maximum.</sub>

Write a program or function that takes the first byte of a UTF-8 byte sequence as input and outputs or returns the length of the sequence. I/O is flexible. For example, the input can be a number, an 8-bit character or a one-character string. You can assume that the first byte is part of a valid sequence and falls into one of the ranges above.

This is code golf. The shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
0x00 => 1
0x41 => 1
0x7F => 1
0xC2 => 2
0xDF => 2
0xE0 => 3
0xEF => 3
0xF0 => 4
0xF4 => 4
```

Comment: Is an input of a list of the 8 bits acceptable?

Comment: @JonathanAllan No, that would be taking flexible I/O too far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Forth, 6 bytes

```
x-size
```

see https://forth-standard.org/standard/xchar/X-SIZE

Input and output follows a standard Forth model:

**Input**

Memory address + length (i.e. 1) of a single-byte UTF-8 "string".

**Output**

UTF-8 sequence length in bytes.

**Sample Code**

Store **0xF0** in a memory cell, and invoke x-size:

```
variable v
0xF0 v !
v 1 x-size
```

Check the result:

```
.s <1> 4  ok
```

Comment: Assuming this works in https://tio.run/#forth-gforth, could you show an example? I don't understand how you could have a single-byte UTF-8 string if the byte is 0xF0.

Comment: > could you show an example? I don't understand how you could have a single-byte UTF-8 string if the byte is 0xF0.

I've added some sample code demonstrating how to do it.

Unfortunately, the TIO version of gforth does not seem to support the Unicode words (according to "see x-size", it is just hard-coded to return 1 there).

Comment: I see. That's not what I'd call an UTF-8 string though, as **F0** alone is an invalid byte sequence, as far as UTF-8 is concerned.

Comment: > as F0 alone is an invalid byte sequence

True (that's why I've put the word "string" in quotes), but this task is specifically about recognizing the sequence by it's first byte, and Forth does not really care for it being invalid, which makes this solution possible, in turn.

Answer (score 6):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), <s>19</s> 14 bytes

```
00000000: 2f6f 3e10 37ed 6a3d 30fb ee07 c03c       /o>.7.j=0....<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcHRCYAwDAXAVd4E9WmgEVF30TYRROi/y0dB7@6RR7s8gr8Jg2eHWE@IWkXepELoO8yoKJSCT9fWpOlcmF5zxAM)

-5 bytes thanks to @Bubbler

[Example with input 0x41-Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BbsIwEETP9VfMjQtKNzVKgBQkjnwFctZ2E2TsKnFQ4eeDDVw7p9HO09v7mn6Cs/NM72whzaoEa9qAiCtIshZ19WVRWWlQkqxhdKWA/aFIoeL6GfZFXZzFy1Bmh5YE2xoDqpkgGf9kR9nxPc/N0f9OcUd/q1I0h3E0l9bdYMMAO3mOffBg5dxWOA21xJPLB7S3aE4cJh@F0joNkj4a5KpG7nssaIEYwMFfzRBz7RM6jDGj64Smt9ypQXTKxQc)
[Assembly](https://tio.run/##TZHLTsMwEEXX9leMWNBWSklaXlUCCxYgWPUPQFPbaYJcO7InVaj672HcgmBh@frOmZe8wdiMRjUeLl7NoPtdB74G5bUpL@DyEhQSPDw8r1/gCLnvKMcYzW5jv@aHVZHzwbiDXJt9Hkm3DuYe5oySMZDTrsvx6rDSbAyDTuXOndY9dT2dG5yKcp2tt3Ueg/rV/9LH6s0x/1gMNwtZPf0MALUPUPdOUesdz2ltKa0GzODEJQM2X2Q@lO8dSdSaA9eFqCBJjKptYVJMgDyv6/YmUJItoyFSQleMclvVYJANWpKyatMcJQSzbSOZACgrf97lv/fXtRRCVDyJ6i2Sgfv3qfXb5XR5e/uOs9nxuJBCdTZBAy/DthS8gs2QbwZLKfgtMFvcsYqqPtvW@y6FUCvR2KyxrLVRgrPEZxBOZb@UFKnuvRTBELiDFK1TgCN/5/gN)

[Example with input 0xC2-Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BbsIwEETP@CvmxgWFJZYSSgAJ9cRXIGdtN0HGrhIHlf58sFuuzGm08/T2d0tfwdl5pld2kIZLsKYPEHEFSdairkqLykqDDckaRlcKOJ6KFCru63As6uIq/g2b7NCSYFtjQDUTJONNDpQd@3luzv57igf6@SxFcxpHc2vdAzYMsJPn2AcPVs7thNNQK/xx@YD2Ec2Fw@SjUFqnQdKiQa5q5L7HkpaIARz83Qwx1z6hwxgzuk1oesudGkSnXHwC)

[Example with input 0xE0-Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BbsIwEETP9VfMjUuVLlhKgAAShx76FZWzXkMq10aJg6A/n9rQa@c02nl6@7OmU/RunukvW2gRAlvagIhraHIOTb1yqJ0WLEk3EFsb4HCscqi6vsVD1VRf6mlYFofVBNeJgBomaMY/2VNx7Oa5/QiXKe3p9k6qPY6jfHf@DhcHuClw6mMAG@@3yluYVzy4ckB3T/LJcQpJGWvzoOmlRalm5L7HghZIERzDVYZUap/RYUwFXWc0v@WzGdTZ@PQL)

[Example with input 0xF4-Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BbsIwEETP9VfMjQtKlxollAASFyS@onLW3pLKtVHioMLPp3bba@c02nl6@9jQe/Qyz/SXLbSTNdjSK4i4hiYRNPWLoBbtsCLdwNnaAIdjlUPV7Tkeqqb6UL@GVXFYTZDOOVDDBM34J3sqjt08t@dwndKevk5r1R7H0X12/g6JA2QKnPoYwMb7rfIWZokfrhzQ3ZN74ziFpIy1edD01KJUM3LfY0ELpAiO4eaGVGqf0WFMBd1kNL/lixnUxfj0DQ)

Assembly:

```
;input: register a
;output: register a
byte_count:			;calculate 7^(log2(255^a))||1
	cpl			;xor 255
	ld l,a
	log2:
		ld	a,16
		scf
	log2loop:
		adc	hl,hl
		dec	a
		jr	nc,log2loop
	xor 7
	ret nz
	inc a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/BasMwDIbP8lPo2EJC2kLXkfS6XvcGHYrsNRmqHWxlpCXvnjmMXXYQ@vXr@wVqKXULk@L5/PZ@wRmrMGhFKbl7K4/y@bqrclG6Y2Xdd5XU9h7LgGVGp8kuTe@HUWuM7tYndRHJNGHU/177UPfBYfRaA0DDJDwKqcPTdSPhdtgcjscrbbfzvDfAg6zQFCJm24BYlIJyz2BtIM9Axf4lq8Sfv7aEMKwrsgydFJ1kbR1DTsFXBM/FH2VgvXsyEJ2ifxroPSMt@fnlBw)

Comment: Use [Bash TIO](https://tinyurl.com/y7kycxpq) to work with assembly, with easier-to-see examples. The link also has 15-byte version of your solution. Here are the improvements: `xor 0xff -> cpl`, no need to `or a`, `jr nz, return -> ret nz`, `ld a,1 -> inc a`.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 39 bytes

```c
t(char x){x=(__builtin_clz(~x)-24)%7u;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BCoMwEEXX5hTBImRQ21QKLqJepBWx0bQDNhaNECr26tYI3bz/hvkMI@OHlOtqmHzWA7Uw25xV1X3CzqCuZPdhXwtxcoEgncSyHlDLbmrabDQN9sdnQVAb@qpRM5iJ54b6WuYzt5xHdOPZMVWOMnFsdm/3bbu72l1dFkE81Q/MHcGcC8xG/LS9YjWc/nblJYgwRCCe9x62pmI@twFPLI0LGjQ37UfbB1hG1DCXAIIs6w8)

Comment: Why `char` and not `int`?

Comment: @R.. Because they get sign extended. For example `~(char)0xF0 == ~(int)0xFFFFFFF0` (assume `char = signed char`, `sizeof(int) == 4`)

Comment: Ah, assuming char is signed.

Comment: You can save five bytes by leaving out the `char ` and just passing `char`s in when you call it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
+⁹BIITḢ
```

A monadic link accepting the byte as an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/7UeNOJ0/PkIc7Fv3//9/I2AIA)** Or see [all inputs evaluated](https://tio.run/##JdIrkhRRFIThrVxPiXvyvi1uPK6jJYaYDSDBsA80CwDNSpiNFH@eiWhXX3Vnn8wvn19fv973h7dvfz6@vHz69/vn/ffH2/dffO778ahXiavoKu0q/SrjKvMq6yr7KodHfszzAAQiIIEJUKACFjjh5O/BCSeccMIJJ5xwDddwzT@Ia7iGa7iGa7iG67iO67juZLiO67iO67iOG7iBG7iBG/4LuIEbuIEbuImbuImbuImb/q@4iZu4iVu4hVu4hVu4hVs@Cm7hFm7jNm7jNm7jNm7jtq@H27iDO7iDO7iDO7iDO7jjM@edfejqS1efuvrW1ceuvnb1uavvXX3w6jfeq/EbWU62k/VkP1lQNpQVuaNwSaFs02@4p3BR4abCVYXW8yqPcMxwznDQcNI4WXV27bKdVc4qZ5WzylnlrHJWOaucVZHz8BvOKmeVs8pZ5axyVjmrck85qPdF@Q0151LOKneVw8pl5bS8LXlc8rrUcob@FQ9MXpg8MXlj8sjUTn6jhyYvTZ6aem63P5//AQ).

If an input of a list of the 8 bits were acceptable then the method is only 6 bytes: `1;IITḢ`, however it has been deemed as talking flexible I/O too far.

#### How?

```
+⁹BIITḢ - Link: integer       e.g.: 127 (7f)            223 (df)            239 (ef)            244 (f4)
 ⁹      - literal 256
+       - add                       383                 479                 495                 500
  B     - to a list of bits         [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1] [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1] [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0]
   I    - increments                [-1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]  [0,0,-1,1,0,0,0,0]  [0,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0]  [0,0,0,0,-1,1,-1,0]
    I   - increments                [2,-1,0,0,0,0,0]    [0,-1,2,-1,0,0,0]   [0,0,-1,2,-1,0,0]   [0,0,0,-1,2,-2,1]
     T  - truthy indices            [1,2]               [2,3,4]             [3,4,5]             [4,5,6,7]
      Ḣ - head                      1                   2                   3                   4
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

```hs
f x=sum[1|y<-"Áßï",x>y]+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBisJAEEX3nuLTCEmISjIIAyHtJpqVs3KpIk1Pa4JJR9ItRnAzJ/EIHiIHy3RpFTxeUfWrEOasqmoYjui4udbb@HFPp6z/65/9i026xX0fxkMtSg2OWlx@DvAvV7ux7VpjhlMTOFalVgY8TXFSNmu0Vdoa3ArVqhHcDaTBAxLpFK0SvxiDebsdQxjCirKCL01AA/MYkgRZIVqX@xSnsNt5rhN4PlGSBWQMfIH3I1M0N/hHyGCIuigaRd08dvjOHbIvhyXZihYrspwsn/8D)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
»Ø⁷Ba\S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q7sMzHjVud0qMCf5/uP1R0xqFyP//DSoMDHQUDCpMDEGkeRqITDYCkSlgdipYNhXMTgOz00wA)

#### How it works

```
»Ø⁷Ba\S  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

 Ø⁷      Yield 128.
»        Take the maximum of n and 128.
   B     Yield the array of binary digits.
    a\   Cumulatively reduce by AND, replacing 1's after the first 0 with 0's.
      S  Take the sum.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda x:1.4**(x/16-11)//1+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LczRCoIwGIbh867iO9x0tf0iBUJXUh1sub@EnDJEFtG1rxQPH154x/f0HEKV@XzNL9u71iI1dKiLQiRNxz2R1JpKyjxEWOXQBVyEScYomHRiqfDXvVrUbvJr85t4Fdfy1uyAMXZhwofFLLEs52UYbXh4YRVcSfKbfw)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 24 bytes

```javascript
x=>7^Math.log2(255^x)||1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcy9CoMwGIXhub2Kb3BIoEqUWie9g04dS8WgiU0JfiUGCf5ce9pkeXjhwPnwhc@9UV@bTjgIv3ADK9Te1U3V3rl9ZxrHghRl2Tq677mXaIgWFhSghCdzjF3gbx6sZLAvgkNsEVcRW8aW1xc9n3qcZtQinJOOuWRTmcWHNWoaSX6jB6QNJNtKFD066n8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>27</s> 23 bytes

```ruby
->x{2+x[7]+(x/16<=>14)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166i2ki7Ito8VlujQt/QzMbWztBEs/Z/dLRBhYGBjoJBhXlarI4CkJdsBOKlQHmpYLlUKC8NzEsziY3Vy00sqK5J1Emq4SpQiAbSOhqJenpJmiBxDbU0Tb3SvMzC2Nr/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
Ｉ⌕⍘⌈⟦Ｎ¹²⁸⟧²0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwy0zL0XDKbE4NbgEKJiu4ZtYkZlbmqsR7ZlXUFriV5qblFqkoamjYGhkEQukjIBYyUBJU1PT@v9/IwOD/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     Ｎ          Input number
      ¹²⁸       Literal 128
   ⌈⟦    ⟧      Take the maximum
  ⍘       ²     Convert to base 2 as a string
 ⌕         0    Find the position of the first `0`
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žy‚àb0k
```

Port of [*@Neil*'s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173562/52210).
-1 byte thanks to *@Grimy*.

Input as integer.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7KRw2zDi9IMsj@/9/I2BIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9kYuLmZ6@k8KhtkoKSvd//o/sqHzXMOrwgySD7v85/AA).

**Explanation:**

```python
žy       # Push 128
  ‚      # Pair it with the (implicit) input-integer
   à     # Take the maximum of this pair (128 and input)
    b    # Convert it to a binary-string
     0k  # Get the 0-based first index of a "0" in this binary-string
         # (and output it implicitly as result)
```

Comment: `s)` to `‚` for 7. Porting the other Jelly answer gives another 8: `₁+b¥η€ËO`

Comment: @Grimy No idea why I didn't had `‚` in the first place.. :S But thanks for -1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
»Ø⁷Bi0’
```

Port of [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173607/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q7sMzHjVud8o0eNQw8////0bGlgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##JdK7kVNREIThVG4AxzjT5@2ShkomBtQmsN6CQwqQAz4GHpuJEhF/z1bJu9@VWtP99fPLy@vz@e/v@8/Htz@fvtTH26/n@4/H9998ns/brZYryqVytXL1co1yzXKtcu1yHR75Mc8DEIiABCZAgQpY4ISTvwcnnHDCCSeccMI1XMM1/yCu4Rqu4Rqu4Rqu4zqu47qT4Tqu4zqu4zpu4AZu4AZu@C/gBm7gBm7gJm7iJm7iJm76v@ImbuImbuEWbuEWbuEWbvkouIVbuI3buI3buI3buI3bvh5u4w7u4A7u4A7u4A7u4I7PnHf2oasvXX3q6ltXH7v62tXnrr539cGr3/ioxm9kOdlO1pP9ZEHZUFbkjsIlhbJNv@GewkWFmwpXFVr3ct3CMcM5w0HDSeNk1dm1y3ZWOaucVc4qZ5WzylnlrHJWRc7DbzirnFXOKmeVs8pZ5azKPeWgPhblN9ScSzmr3FUOK5eV0/K25HHJ61LLGfpXPDB5YfLE5I3JI1M7@Y0emrw0eWrqud1@v/8H).

**Explanation:**

```python
 Ø⁷        # Push 128
»          # Take the max of 128 and the input
   B       # Convert it to binary
    i0     # Get the 1-indexed first index of a 0
      ’    # Decrease it by 1 to make it 0-indexed (and output it implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 18 bytes

```perl6
{7-msb(255-$_)||1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2lw3tzhJw8jUVFclXrOmxrD2vzVXcWKlglK1XlpuiYa6qoFRhLpmrYKtnUJ1mgZQTa2SQlp@kYJBhYGBDpA0MQSR5m4g0tkIRLqA2a5gWVcw2w3MdjP5DwA)

Port of user202729's JavaScript answer. Alternatives with WhateverCode:

```perl6
(255-*).msb*6%34%7
-(255-*).msb%6%5+1
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86 Assembly, 11 bytes

```
00000000 <f>:
   0:   f6 d1                   not    %cl
   2:   0f bd c1                bsr    %ecx,%eax
   5:   34 07                   xor    $0x7,%al
   7:   75 01                   jne    a <l1>
   9:   40                      inc    %eax
0000000a <l1>:
   a:   c3                      ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDhasMgGPwdn@IjWyDSZDPZoNC0fZEuBGu0cxgzEguy0ldf9hk2Skb9cZx39@mpyE9CTNODtsKcWwnb0bW6f3rfE6Ktg6bhzg36eHayadJU8dEJbgyloFL0aUUwMXbokVhtYLHebExisL0DSIRZiMdxQFEKnyWS@1/R9yg@rrOEm1vyw0oAUyzPxLJhHCdvoik2d24fpPsvYuf5aR3XNqUXEoUNP9S7C/OMZYBYBFyrgKIM2M5czq6cuZq5er1WJFL9ED4D9I5VejvqL9mrlNPnP3ZgNa1WK01JFH0OmFRpzHzCSg/5HpIWW2XYQNcZhLSuKXa8TtO3UIafxinvXsof)

Port of user202729's JavaScript answer. Uses fastcall conventions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 35 bytes

```
? @!1 16/ )!@!
:   ";_ _3&""2
_128&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fXsFB0VDB0ExfQVPRQZHLSkFBQck6XiHeWE1JyYgr3tDIQu3/fyMTAwA)

Unwrapped version of the code:

```
?:_128&1!@
      ;
      _16/_3&2!@
            )
            !
            @
```

Comment: You're missing an `!` on the third line, which means doesn't print anything for inputs below 128

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 28 bytes

```
1?:_128/}:_224/}_240/{{+++!@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f0N4q3tDIQr/WKt7IyES/Nt7IxEC/ulpbW1vR4f9/IAcA)

Routing is pretty hard and also takes a lot of bytes, so I figured I'd just make a linear program. Basically computes `1 + n/128 + n/224 + n/240`, where `/` is floor division.

Comment: The `1+` can just be `)`

Answer (score 0):

## C, 31 bytes

```c
f(x){return(x-160>>20-x/16)+2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7RCoIwFIav3VMMI9jQ1VHCLla@RhflhcytDtgMNRiJr95yQjcf3@H85/ArcVfKe8Mcn3o9vnvLnMgKKMschNtnBU9yOfsNWtW@G30axga73aMkaEf6rNEyPpEoDPW1Ok/gAFK6MAs8mkCVBzar63WrVzerm8MsSWS6noUneAaJpwE/ujOs5vu/XaHiMkmQkyh69UvSsBjcFnJHRUm3zc3G6dIAq5SGNFacSzL7rzJtfR@8uNhO4PPVosJRLOc/)

#### 27 bytes with gcc (-O0)

```c
f(x){x=(x-160>>20-x/16)+2;}
```

#### Alternatives, 31 and 33 bytes

```c
f(x){return(10>>15-x/16)+7>>2;}
f(x){return x/128-(-3>>15-x/16);}
```

I found these expressions when playing around with the Aha! superoptimizer [a few years ago](http://blogs.perl.org/users/nick_wellnhofer/2015/04/branchless-utf-8-length.html).

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 42 bytes

```sh
>$1
eval ';od>><'{,194,224,240}-\>
wc -l<*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fTsWQK7UsMUdB3To/xc7ORr1ax9DSRMfICIhNDGp1Y@y4ypMVdHNstP7//29oaQkA)

Input as a decimal integer.