# Decode a UTF-8 string to character byte counts

Tags: code-golf, string, unicode

Given a UTF-8 string, give a string that represents byte counts of each characters.

**Rules:**

1. As long as the input string is encoded in UTF-8 **(without BOM)**, its type doesn't matter. In C++, it can be `char[]` or `std::string`. In Haskell, it can be `[Int8]` or `[CChar]`.
2. The output must be (in usual case) a string of ASCII digit characters. Its encoding doesn't matter.
3. When given an invalid UTF-8 sequence (including representation of surrogates), **every bytes** of the sequence are to be represented as the replacement character �.
4. Reserved characters and noncharacters are still considered as valid UTF-8 sequences, and thus must have corresponding output digit.
5. As this is a code-golf, the shortest code in bytes wins.

**Example:**

When given the following byte sequence:

```
00 80 C0 80 EB 80 80
```

The output must be:

```
1���3
```

Comment: Recommended test case: `b'Hej d\xc3\xc5!'` (i.e. `48 65 6A 20 64 C3 C5 21`) (invalid continuation byte (C5) after a valid start byte (C3)) (expected output: `11111��1`)

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/173520/43319)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 135 bytes

```python
def f(b):
	B=b.decode(errors="ignore")[:1].encode();l=len(B)
	if B and b[:l]!=B:return"�"+f(b[1:])
	return str(l)+f(b[l:])if b else''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCoMwEEXXeoqYTRIKokihpGSTUugd1IWasbWERKIFe7jSI/UIadBCF8OH9/6f8TnfrCm8V9CjnraMx5EUbaqgswooOGfdJPBwNdYBZiXP6xTM6thRCw2GShZHQ48kaoxCbcl1nQjJHcwPZ/Dn/cK78LfMeR16G0XT7KhmK9eBh3WLQE9AiB/dYGYaDKmWLKuWQ7jTL89yy0NGGIv/zQvckaqWrqiWZp8E578)

Explanation:

```python
def f(b):
	B=b.decode(errors="ignore")[:1].encode();l=len(B)
	 # B is the UTF-8-encoded version of the first Unicode character in the given bytes
	 # (Or the Nth, if the first N-1 bytes were invalid Unicode bytes)
	if B and b[:l]!=B:return"�"+f(b[1:])
	 # If the two encoded byte-strings don't match,
	 # then the first byte in b is invalid,
	 # so append "�" to the returned string, and recurse
	return str(l)+f(b[l:])if b else''
	 # If the byte-string is not empty,
	 #  append the length of the first character and recurse.
	 # Else (the input is empty) return the empty string (recursion base case)
```